# Can I move MySQL table to a second drive?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I am having I/O related performance problems that would be solved if a few relatively small tables were running on a SSD.  I can't move the entire DB to SSD because it is much too large.

I thought this was possible (map specific tables to different drives) but a tech at my managed hosting company says that the entire DB needs to be in a single directory.  Is this correct?  If he's wrong, can someone point me somewhere with basic instructions on how this is done?  Or even provide the instructions here?

Comment: You've tagged both MySQL and SQL Server. The latter is a different product from Microsoft. I suppose you only ask for MySQL, right?

Comment: What engine does your table(s) use? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: The tables are currently all MyISAM, but could be changed. My mistake on the tag.  It is MySQL I am asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a MySQL table you can specify the `data directory` and `index directory`.
Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

So, to answer your question, you could create a new table in the different directory and migrate your data there.

Comment: Thanks cherouvim.  This is exactly what I needed to know.  It looks fairly simple.  The hosting tech was clearly wrong.